# mean groupby depending on two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, mean

I have a table which looks like the following example.

```
  Timestamp Scan_ID LOS_ID  ... Radial_Wind_Speed_[m/s] CNR_[dB] Confidence_Index_Status
0      2019-04-04 23:01:00.147      26      4  ...                    0.04   -11.66                       1
1      2019-04-04 23:01:00.147      26      4  ...                   -0.18   -12.89                       1
2      2019-04-04 23:01:00.147      26      4  ...                    0.00   -12.27                       1
3      2019-04-04 23:01:00.147      26      4  ...                    0.12   -10.58                       1
4      2019-04-04 23:01:00.147      26      4  ...                    0.17    -6.32                        1
```

For further plotting i want to make means, which depends on the altitude and the dequence_number.

Is it possible to get means which depends on two values like:

```
df.groupby(['Altitude_[m]']).mean()
```

Best
and Thanks

Comment: What do you plot means (of what) against?

Comment: Hi, I wan't a mean for every measurement periode (Sequence_ID) a mean for every Altitude. That mean, that the Sequence ID is for one periode the same, but the Altitude is different for every row. After n rows the alteitude repeats and after m rows the Sequence ID change.

Comment: With `df.groupby(['Altitude_[m]']).mean()` (i now this is wrong) I get a mean for my n heights, and every measurement. But i want for every time periode (Sequence ID) one mean depending on height. I hope now it is a bit clearlier.

Comment: `df.groupby(['Sequence ID','Altitude_[m]']).mean()`?